# Render plotly plots asynchronously in shiny app

Tags: r, asynchronous, shiny, promise, plotly

In shiny app I render couple plotly plots at once, but they render only after all of them are calculated. For example, if rendering 8 of 9 plots  takes 8 seconds and rendering 9th takes 15 seconds, the first 8 plots will appear only after 9th is rendered (after 15 seconds instead of 8). See example below.

`box_plot1` appears only when `box_plot2` is rendered. I played a bit with shiny promises, but didn't find solution so far.

**MWE:**

```
library(shinydashboard)
library(plotly)

header <- dashboardHeader(
  title = ""
)

body <- dashboardBody(
  fluidRow(
    column(width = 6,
           box(width = NULL, solidHeader = TRUE,
               plotly::plotlyOutput("box_plot1")
           )
    ),
    column(width = 6,
           box(width = NULL, solidHeader = TRUE,
               plotly::plotlyOutput("box_plot2")
           )
    )
  )
)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  header,
  dashboardSidebar(disable = TRUE),
  body
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$box_plot1 <- plotly::renderPlotly({
    p <- plot_ly(ggplot2::diamonds, x = ~cut, y = ~price, color = ~clarity, type = "box") %>%
      layout(boxmode = "group")

    p
  })

  output$box_plot2 <- plotly::renderPlotly({

    for (i in 1:3) {
      print(i)
      Sys.sleep(1)
    }

    plot_ly(ggplot2::diamonds, y = ~price, color = ~cut, type = "box")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: This is not possible because of the inherent event loop in shiny, which is baked into the design of the shiny server. You can read more about this under the flush cycle here: https://rstudio.github.io/promises/articles/shiny.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `renderUI` in combination with `reactiveValues` which keep track of the order of the calculations.

```
library(shinydashboard)
library(plotly)

header <- dashboardHeader(
    title = ""
)

body <- dashboardBody(
    fluidRow(
        column(width = 6,
               uiOutput("plot1")
        ),
        column(width = 6,
               uiOutput("plot2")
        )
    )
)

ui <- dashboardPage(
    header,
    dashboardSidebar(disable = TRUE),
    body
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

    rv <- reactiveValues(val = 0)


    output$plot1 <- renderUI({

        output$box_plot1 <- plotly::renderPlotly({

            for (i in 3:5) {
                print(i)
                Sys.sleep(1)
            }

            p <- plot_ly(ggplot2::diamonds, x = ~cut, y = ~price, color = ~clarity, type = "box") %>%
                layout(boxmode = "group")
            rv$val <- 1
            p
        })

        return(
            tagList(
                box(width = NULL, solidHeader = TRUE,
                    plotly::plotlyOutput("box_plot1")
                )
            )
        )

    })



    output$plot2 <- renderUI({

        if(rv$val == 0) {
            return(NULL)
        }

        output$box_plot2 <- plotly::renderPlotly({

            for (i in 1:3) {
                print(i)
                Sys.sleep(1)
            }

            plot_ly(ggplot2::diamonds, y = ~price, color = ~cut, type = "box")
        })

        return(
            tagList(
                box(width = NULL, solidHeader = TRUE,
                    plotly::plotlyOutput("box_plot2")
                )
            )
        )

    })



}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 4):

The answer by @DSGym works in showing one plot after another but this still does not function asynchronously. In fact if you have a plot which takes a long time to render or a data frame which take a long time to calculate, we need to perform these operations asynchronously. As an example consider this regular shiny app with no asynchronous support,

```
library(shinydashboard)
library(plotly)
library(future)
library(promises)

plan(multisession)

header <- dashboardHeader(
  title = ""
)

body <- dashboardBody(
  fluidRow(
    column(width = 6,
           box(width = NULL, solidHeader = TRUE,
               plotly::plotlyOutput("box_plot1")
           )
    ),
    column(width = 6,
           box(width = NULL, solidHeader = TRUE,
               plotly::plotlyOutput("box_plot2")
           )
    )
  )
)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  header,
  dashboardSidebar(disable = TRUE),
  body
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$box_plot1 <- plotly::renderPlotly({

      for (i in 1:10) {
        print(i)
        Sys.sleep(1)
      }

      plot_ly(ggplot2::diamonds, x = ~cut, y = ~price, color = ~clarity, type = "box") %>%
        layout(boxmode = "group")
  })

  output$box_plot2 <- plotly::renderPlotly({


      for (i in 11:20) {
        print(i)
        Sys.sleep(1)
      }

      plot_ly(ggplot2::diamonds, y = ~price, color = ~cut, type = "box")


  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Each plot counts to 10 and shows its output. The whole operation takes 20+ seconds to complete from when `runApp()` is executed.

To call both the plots asynchronously we use the futures and promises package.

```
library(shinydashboard)
library(plotly)
library(future)
library(promises)

plan(multisession)

header <- dashboardHeader(
  title = ""
)

body <- dashboardBody(
  fluidRow(
    column(width = 6,
           box(width = NULL, solidHeader = TRUE,
               plotly::plotlyOutput("box_plot1")
           )
    ),
    column(width = 6,
           box(width = NULL, solidHeader = TRUE,
               plotly::plotlyOutput("box_plot2")
           )
    )
  )
)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  header,
  dashboardSidebar(disable = TRUE),
  body
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$box_plot1 <- plotly::renderPlotly({
    future({
      for (i in 1:10) {
        print(i)
        Sys.sleep(1)
      }

      plot_ly(ggplot2::diamonds, x = ~cut, y = ~price, color = ~clarity, type = "box") %>%
        layout(boxmode = "group")
    })
  })

  output$box_plot2 <- plotly::renderPlotly({

    future({
      for (i in 11:20) {
        print(i)
        Sys.sleep(1)
      }

      plot_ly(ggplot2::diamonds, y = ~price, color = ~cut, type = "box")
    })

  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Now, even though both plots count up to 10, the plots execute asynchronously. The total time to load the plots reduced to below 20 seconds.

However, both plots still load together. This is because of the inherent flush cycle in shiny. Hence, even if we execute the plots asynchronously, all plots will always load at the same time.

You can read more about this here: https://rstudio.github.io/promises/articles/shiny.html